# Why does the proof show a trigonometric polynomial is algebraic?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading Chapter11 of Real Analysis, Carthoers, 1ed. Here is a proof that try to show a trigonometric polynomial is actually an algebraic polynomial,
[image]

I have two questions about it:

1. Why do we need to show algebra structure of trigonometric polynomial?
2. Does there exist any other structure of polynomial? If so, can you show me some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your second question, there are [exponential polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_polynomial), which are defined analogously and are often used in transcendence theory.

Comment: Ok, make sense^_^

Answer (score 1):

"Why do we **need to**"?  I don't personally feel that much of a need, but I would guess that this is going to be an ingredient in Lebesgue's proof.

Comment: If I remove this part from Lebesgue's proof, or say I do not prove the algebra structure of a trigonometric polynomial, what will happen next?

Comment: Then you are missing part of the proof.  What happens next depends on whether you care about having complete proofs.